# Android : get the id of dynamically generated ImageButton when clicked

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton

I have dynamically generated ImageButtons with different ImageResource for each ImageButton. Now I want to know which ImageButton was clicked, how can I determine this ?
Need your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set an id for each created `ImageButton`  and `getId()` for check witch button clicked

```
    ImageButton im=new ImageButton(Yourcontext);
    im.setId(giveAnID);

     //where you check 
    int theID=im.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you could do two things:

Firstly, when dynamically generated the ImageButton you could call setId() in order to set a specific id to this View and store it in List, etc.

Then when you have a click event (or anything else), you can call the getId() method of the View to get the id.

Then you can compare and do anything you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Any resource is uniquely identified by its id which is generated in R.java file.
So you can use something like :

```
if(image.getId() == R.id.image) {
  // do awesome stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code generates the imageButtons then, in this code you can write something like,

```
imageButton.setId(1);
```

and when your imageButton is clicked then you can get it with,

```
int id = imageButton.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

i had to do same thing and this is what i have done

```
         for(int i = 0 ;i<mediaList.size();i++){
        view_media_gallery_item = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.e_media_gallery_item, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) view_media_gallery_item.findViewById(R.id.media_gallery_item_title);
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) view_media_gallery_item.findViewById(R.id.media_gallery_item_subtitle);
        ImageView flux_Title_Image =(ImageView) view_media_gallery_item.findViewById(R.id.media_gallery_item_img);

        title.setId(i+100);
        subtitle.setId(i+1000);
        flux_Title_Image.setId(2000+i);
        title.setText("" +mediaList.get(i).getTitle());
        subtitle.setText(""+mediaList.get(i).getArtist());
        System.out.println("view added::::");
        view_media_gallery_item.setTag(mediaList.get(i));
        view_media_gallery_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("view media clicked");
                Media m = (Media )v.getTag();
                medialistner.setOnItemclick(m); 
            }
        });
```